# GET request through an API in angular 2 generates 500 error

Tags: angular

This is my HTML code where I have a click function which calls my API.

```
   <li class="nav-item tabu">       
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab"  href="#assumtion" (click)= "getFavourite(careerPathId)" role="tab" aria-controls="assumtion" aria-expanded="false"
            style="text-align: center">FAVOURITES</a>
    </li>
```

Below is my service method where I am passing a token in headers.

```
getFavouriteUniversity(careerPathUID){
let headers = new Headers;
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
let token = 'Bearer ' + authToken;
headers.append('Authorization', `${token}`);
return this.http.get
(this.webUrl + '/api/Students/GetShortListedUniversities?careerPathUID=' + careerPathUID,
                                                                                        {headers} )
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
.catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

}
```

I am passing my careerpathUID using this method in my component.ts file.

```
  getFavourite(careerPathUID){

  this.universityService.getFavouriteUniversity(careerPathUID).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.careerPathUID = careerPathUID;
       let anyObj1 = <UniversityModel>data;
        this.universities = anyObj1;
        this.universityArray.push(anyObj1);
    });

}
```

I am getting this error.

[image: I am getting this error.]

Comment: It's a server error, so unless the URL is malformed or something, the error is unrelated to the code in this question.

Comment: There was a problen in the API code is working properly thankyou for the help.

Comment: In my case, calling the api method which is decorated with 'AllowAnonymous' (but the class is decorated with 'JWTAuthentication') throws this error. Direct call to api method works but from angular 4 doesn't.

Removing 'JWTAuthentication' from class and added to individual methods, solved this issue.